# Support for strided iteration by the C++ ranged-for loop mechanism

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, range, stride

The conceptual "model" of C++ ranged-for loops is of advancing a 'current' iterator until reaching some single 'point' of the end-of-iteration. To be more specific, writing:

```
for(auto x : range) /* ... */
```

[is](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) the equivalent of writing (with a little simplification and ignoring lifetime extension needs etc.):

```
auto __end = range.end();
for (auto __iter = range.begin(); __iter != __end; ++__iter) {
    auto x = *__iter;
    /* ... */
}
```

But what happens when the end is not a single point, but a larger set of possible states/values?

Specifically, suppose we're iterating a range of integers, but advancing by *k* at each iteration, not by just 1. In a classic, plain, C-style loop this would work as follows:

```
for (i = n_start; i < n_end; i += k) /* ... */
```

and note the comparison is using an order relation, not equality. If one naively implemented a strided iterator, with

```
strided_iterator& strided_iterator::operator++() { 
    pos_ += stride_; 
    return *this;
}
bool operator==(const strided_iterator& lhs, const strided_iterator& rhs) {
    return lhs.pos_ == rhs.pos_;
}
```

and then an integer range class whose `begin()` and `end()` return `strided_iterator`s - a ranged-for loop on this range would usually be an *infinite loop*: the ranged-for `__iter` would simply jump right over `__end` - from being lower than `__end` to being higher, never stopping.

My questions:

1. In C++17, I could overcome this problem by defining a sentinel type and "cheating": Letting its "equality" operator against `strided_iterator` actually perform an order-comparison. But is there a more elegant solution?
2. In C++14 or earlier, I could implement an uglier hack: A single iterator class which has two "modes", a regular strided iterator and a sentinel as per the above, with the constructor choosing which mode the iterator uses. Or - a virtual operator== and two subclasses for these two modes. Is there a more elegant solution?
3. Why do ranged-for loops not allow for order-based rather than equality-based comparison, somehow? Or perhaps more generally - replacing the concept of a sentinel with a predicate for end-of-iteration, to be applied to the iterator after every iteration?

---

<sub>PS - If you think I should split (3.) into a separate question, please say so in a comment.</sub>

Comment: Imagine iterator to a list (or set or map) and how order operator would work for it!

Comment: @MarekR: Naturally, if you want a strided range for a simple linked list, you have no choice but to pay the pay the price of a highly-expensive order-comparison operator. However, you could arrange your list so that after the last node, you have a dummy node whose "next" pointer points to itself. With that in place, you could have a sentinel class for your list with a cheap comparison operator!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of this question. Range-based loop is a syntax sugar for the most common operation on container - iterating over it. Other operations like striding or partial iteration are relatively rare, and you can use regular for loop syntax for that. Current definition of range-based loop has an advantage of working with every type of iterator, not only random access ones. But I suppose you know all that, seeing that you have a gold badge in C++ and C++11. So what exactly would you like to see in place of current syntax?

Comment: One of the design principles for the standard library mentioned in [the `CppCon 2016 presentation about STL algoritms`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4Jl1fk3MkQ) is to reduce the number of operators used to a minimum and the `!=` operator should be available for all iterator types.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: 1. Well, it's the wrong syntactic sugar for an important class of iteration scenarios. Strided iteration is very straightforward; and not that rare. But I suppose "rarity" is an answer one can agree or disagree with. 2. The syntax is fine, it's the semantics I would expect to be different, as I've explained abouve.

Comment: @fabian: But I didn't suggest a _requirement_ of more operators; rather, _support_ for the case of more or other operators being available. In the strided case, a sentinel is _not_ naturally equality-comparable with an iterator.

Comment: You also have to fix the problem that `pos_ += stride_;` (or `std::advance(it, stride)`) is UB if you increment past the end. Having fixed that, `==` does fine

Comment: @Caleth: Why would I necessarily have UB? Suppose my range really is just pure integers. No problem in being n_end + 7 ; it's just out of the range.

Comment: I was assuming you wanted an iterator adaptor. If you are writing a concrete int stride range, just ensure that end's `pos_ % stride_` is 0. Do some arithmetic in the body of `strided_range::strided_range(int start, int end, int stride)`

Comment: @Caleth: % is an expensive operator. It is extremely un-C++-like for the abstraction of a ranged-for loop to make me have to use `%`. But - that is technically an answer.

Comment: What's wrong with `for (auto i = n_start; i < n_end; i += k)` then? why do you need `for (auto i : strided(n_start, n_end, k))`?

Comment: @Caleth: The same thing that is "wrong" with `for(i = n_start; i < n_end; i++)`...

Comment: It seems to me that you are looking for a strided *view* of a range, to ensure that what returned by `begin`, `end` and any comparator make sense all together.

Comment: @Bob__: Well, yes, you could phrase it like that. And more specifically - I can already do that, except that my idea seems ugly.

Comment: My point is that, if you focus on the "concept" of strided object, the needed iterators descend "naturally", you can enforce the end iterator (returned by `end()`) to be exactly "where" it needs to be to avoid an infinite loop (`distance(begin, end)` equal to some multiple of the stride). That doesn't seem particularly ugly to me.

Comment: I don't understand this question. When a container is created, it's assigned a size of `size= n*sizeof(T)` bytes, and iterator **__end** is set to the next byte after `size`. If you create your own container with own iterators with a *stride* different that `sizeof(T)` then you can not use `__iter != __end`, you're breaking the rules. Why do you need this?

Comment: @Ripi2 Consider this example: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.strides.html

Comment: @Ripi2: 1. This question is not about containers (although it's relevant to some containers). 2. "and iterator __end is set to the next byte after size" <- No. That might be true for some specific containers, whose iterators are pointers. It's not true for, say, `std::list<T>`.

Comment: @Bob__: I'm not quite sure I see what you mean - but perhaps you can expand on that comment in a proper answer? You seem to have one.

Comment: I was just thinking about `ranges::views::stride` from `range/v3`, but I'm not sure [this](https://godbolt.org/z/jaqebqeja) could be an answer to all the questions you posted.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to (1.):

One approach you could take is Eric Niebler's, in his range-v3 library:

- Use a *bounded* strided iterator instead of an unbounded one.
- Construct the strided iterator with the bound being the end of your range.

Now, the iterator's advancement members will include a bound-check, so that instead of advancing past the end, it is set to the end (or perhaps I should say the end's position). Then, it will actually compare equal to an end sentinel defined as a simple unstrided iterator encapsulating a given integral position.

Ostensibly, this means that you'll be doubling the number of instructions used to check whether to exit the loop, on each iteration: The semi-compiled pseudocode will be something like

```
/* ... */
pos <- pos + stride
if (pos > end_pos)
   pos <- end_pos
if (pos == end_pos)
   break the loop
next iteration
```

and a gracious compiler may note that it's sufficient to check `pos >= end_pos` only.

This will work in C++17. It won't help you with the problem of the sentinel having to have the same type as the iterator in C++14 and earlier.

---

<sub>Thanks goes to @Bob for suggesting I have a look at range-v3's stride adapter. It takes a bit of digging to understand where the problem I've brought up is addressed...</sub>